# Convert integers into binary

Tags: beginner, c, number-systems

I've made a very simple program that takes integer number arguments either with plus/minus sign or without them, and print the number in binary format.

**binary.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printBinary(int);
int toInt(int*, char[]);
int handleProgram(char[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    return handleProgram(argv[1]);
}

int handleProgram(char param[])
{
    int number, state;

    if( toInt( &number, param ) != -1 )
    {
        printBinary(number);

        state = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\tmain()::Exiting program...\n");

        state = -1;
    }

    return state;
}


void printBinary(int number)
{
    for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (number >> i & 1 == 1)
            putchar('1');
        else
            putchar('0');

        if (i != 0)
        {
            if (i % 4 == 0)
                putchar(' ');

            if (i % 16 == 0)
                printf(": ");
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int toInt(int *num, char param[])
{
    *num = 0;
    int sign = 1;
    int i = 0;

    if(param == NULL)
    {
        printf("\ttoInt()::No parameter, please enter a valid number!\n");

        return -1;
    }

    if(param[i] == '-')
    {
        sign = -1;
        i++;
    }
    else if( param[i] == '+' )
    {
        i++;
    }

    // check that a number exist
    if(param[i] == '\0')
    {
        printf("\ttoInt()::No number detected, please enter a valid number\n");

        return -1;
    }

    for(; param[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(param[i] >= '0' && param[i] <= '9')
            *num = 10* *num + param[i] - '0';
        else
        {
            printf("\ttoInt()::Invalid parameter, please enter a valid number!\n");

            return -1;
        }
    }

    *num *= sign;

    return 0;
}
```

**Sample output: positive and negative cases**

> ```
> D:\C\chapter2>gcc binary.c -o binary.exe
>
> D:\C\chapter2>binary 3
> 0000 0000 0000 0000 : 0000 0000 0000 0011
>
> D:\C\chapter2>binary +3
> 0000 0000 0000 0000 : 0000 0000 0000 0011
>
> D:\C\chapter2>binary -3
> 1111 1111 1111 1111 : 1111 1111 1111 1101
>
> D:\C\chapter2>binary +3s
>         toInt()::Invalid parameter, please enter a valid number!
>         main()::Exiting program...
>
> D:\C\chapter2>binary -3s
>         toInt()::Invalid parameter, please enter a valid number!
>         main()::Exiting program...
>
> D:\C\chapter2>binary s
>         toInt()::Invalid parameter, please enter a valid number!
>         main()::Exiting program...
>
> D:\C\chapter2>binary +
>         toInt()::No number detected, please enter a valid number
>         main()::Exiting program...
>
> D:\C\chapter2>binary -
>         toInt()::No number detected, please enter a valid number
>         main()::Exiting program...
>
> D:\C\chapter2>binary
>         toInt()::No parameter, please enter a valid number!
>         main()::Exiting program...
> ```

Any ideas for a better approach (where to fix, what to do about negative cases, any more functions need)?

Comment: If your aim is writing elegant code making use of existing standard libraries, then the function `strtol` (in stdlib) is the way to go (the man page includes a comprehensive example on how to use it), and can reduce your code by half. Even though your code doesn't require IO performance, it's good practice using a buffer for constructing your output and print only once rather than on multiple little chunks.

Comment: I want to build up everything like reinventing the wheel. That's why I didn't used stdlib functions. I've used to code in C in the field however after 3 years, I want to go deep to be a better programmer thus started from the page no:1 of the Kernighan's book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Functionality**

1. Why 31?  Why not 15 or 63 or 42?  If code is to handle 32-bit integers, then use `long` as that type is at least 32-bit, rather than `int`, which can be as small as 16.  Alternatives `int32_t`, `int_least32_t`.  Even better: re-code for the largest integer type `intmax_t`.

   ```
   // Why 31?
   for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
   ```
2. Right shifting a negative number leads to implementation defined behavior.  Consider `unsigned` instead.

   ```
   // ... (int number)
   ... (unsigned number)
   ... 
   if (number >> i & 1 == 1)
   ```
3. Good that code allows a leading `'+'`.
4. Pedantic point.  `int` overflow is undefined behavior and that is the result of the following with `argv[1] == "-2147483648"`, a string that should "work".

   ```
   *num = 10* *num + param[i] - '0';
   ```
5. Avoid using `printf(some_string)`.  Should `some_string` contain a `%`, maybe due to a code update, that will invoke UB as `printf()` expects the first arg to be a *format* string.

   ```
   // printf(": ");
   fputs(": ", stdout);
   // or (2nd choice)
   printf("%s", ": ");
   ```
6. Do not use `argv[1]` unless it  is valid

   ```
   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {   
     if (argc > 1) return handleProgram(argv[1]);
     else ...
   ```
7. Prefer terminating error messages to go to `stderr`

   ```
   // printf("\ttoInt()::No number detected, ...
   fprintf(stderr, "\ttoInt()::No number detected, ...
   ```
8. Overflow not detected in `toInt()`.

**Style**

1. Avoid naked magic numbers.  Consider

   ```
   // for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
   #define INT_WIDTH  32
   for (int i = INT_WIDTH - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   ```
2. `int toInt()` returns only 2 different `int`.  Consider `bool`.

**Minor**

1. See little value in excessive in vertical spacing throughout code.  Example: The need for a blank line between buys little clarity for the price of a line.

   ```
   printBinary(number);

   state = 0;
   ```
2. Consider parens `()`

   ```
   // if (number >> i & 1 == 1)
   if ((number >> i) & 1 == 1)
   // or simply
   if ((number >> i) & 1)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Two things about your code.

First, try putting all of your constants in macros. This will make your code more readable and less change-error prone.

Second, you assume that all of your input integers are signed. But if the user doesn't want a signed int and wants to convert an unsigned int to binary he would get one major difference:
The int range is two times smaller.

I suggest you ask for input like s* if * is a signed number or u* if * is unsigned.
Also change / add a function to handle this case.

Comment: I would also specify signed long ints

Comment: I disagree. macros are hard to debug at best, and it clutters up the code.

I personally only use macros for values I want to be editable.